# Passing an argument into an unknown URL in Python

Tags: python, oop, web, web-crawler, screen-scraping

```
make = raw_input("Enter car make: ")
model = raw_input("Enter car model: ")

htmlText = urllib.urlopen("http://www.carsearch.com/+ make + "/" + model).read()(easy)
```

Is it possible to pass these variables to a URL that is not known.

for example.

```
url = ("Enter URL: )
htmlText = urllib.urlopen(url + make + model).read() (Obviously wouldn't work)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Simply create a string (called `fullurl` in the code snippet bellow) and pass it to `urllib.urlopen()`.

```
make = raw_input("Enter car make: ")
model = raw_input("Enter car model: ")
url = raw_input("Enter URL: ")

fullurl = "%s/%s/%s"%(url,make,model,)
htmlText = urllib.urlopen(fullurl).read()
```

---

You can use `urllib.urlencode()` if you need to pass the variables as parameters. An example is listed at [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#examples).

Comment: Yes, but I want to pass those variables to structurally different URL's that take the data in different ways. For example. http://www.carzone.ie/used-cars/make/model, www.cars.com/make- make/model- model/used_cars, how would I go about that? The above example will only work for some URL's but not all.

Comment: Realizing this is no problem. The only work we have to do is to define the different types of urls (and the positions in the url where we have to place `make` and `models`) and we also need to let the python program know the one url type we'd like to generate. E.g. could to this with `urltype = raw_input("Enter URL type (1=type1, 2=type2): ")`. Can you please edit your question and add the different urltypes (with examples)?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but what If i didn't know the URL and It was added dynamically but i still wanted those arguments to be passed to the newly added user given URL.

Comment: Then you need to parse the URL to get the position where to paste make and model. I think you need to provide a full example URL like `http://www.carsearch.com/BMW/F10` or `http://www.carsearch1.com/search?make=BMW&model=F10` and so on. If your URL has some keywords in it like `make` and `model` or you have an URL which leads to some specific car like `BMW` and `F10` it won`t be so difficult to parse the URL. Can you provide such URLs to the final code?

Comment: What I did was I tried to make search requests to google and parse the top result, but this would not work using urllib, so I decided to use mechanize and that worked. code below.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use google search to aggregate my query.
Solution:
[Get links method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZY2S.png)

[get values and regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCVgm.png)